# post ajax data with click a link on laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

I'm newbie in ajax and laravel 5

I have some problem about passing data when I click a link, I gonna explain you what I want achieve.

**here my html code :**

```
//this is the div that i want append with data foreach
<div id="warung-plain">
</div>

//and those code is links that when i click it will send ajax data
@foreach($kategoriwarung_all as $kategoriwarung)
    <li style="padding:5px 0px">
        <a class="kategori-warung" style="text-decoration:none;color:#5ca4a9" href="#">
           {{ $kategoriwarung->nama }}
        </a>
    </li>
 @endforeach

//this is a html code that i want plain in id="warung-plain" after get the foreach data
<div class="row" style="margin:3% 0px 0px 0px" id="">
@foreach($warung_has_kategoriwarungs[$category_fix] as $Warung)
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:0px;min-height:100px">
        <ul class="no-padding" style="display:inline-flex;list-style-type: none;width:100%;">
            <li>
                <img class="img-circle" src="assets/gambar_contoh/foto.jpg" style="height:60px;width:60px">
            </li>
            <li style="padding:0px 0px 0px 15px ;width:100%">
                <p class="heading-toko-font" style="font-size:18px;color:#606060">{{ $Warung->Warung->nama  }}</p>
                <span class="alamat-toko-font" style="font-size:14px;color:#BCBCBC"><?php echo $Warung['Warung']['alamat']; ?></span>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
@endforeach                        
</div>
```

here is my js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".kategori-warung").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            var category = $(e.target).text();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //after passing data category then system will append 
                //html code to id="warung-plain"
                url: "/ambil_kategori/{category}",
                data: {category: category},
                success: function(res) {
                    $('#warung-plain').load("/warung_plain/{category}");
                }
            });   
            $(".warung").fadeIn("slow").show();
            $("#nama-kategori").html(category);
            $(".warung-semua").hide();  
        });
    });
</script>
```

**this is my controller:**

```
public function index()
{   
    $Warungs_all = Warung::paginate(10);
    $kategoriwarung_all = kategoriwarung::all();


    return view('index' , compact('kategoriwarung_all' , 'Warungs_all' ));
}


public function get_warung_by_category($category){

    $category_fix = $category;
    $kategoriwarung_all = kategoriwarung::all();

    foreach($kategoriwarung_all as $kategoriwarung){
        $kategoriwarung->nama;
        $kategoriwarung->id;
        $warung_has_kategoriwarungs[$kategoriwarung->nama] = warung_has_kategoriwarung::where('kategoriwarung_id' , '=' , $kategoriwarung->id)->with(['Warung','kategoriwarung'])->paginate(10);
    }

    return view('daftar_warung' , compact('warung_has_kategoriwarungs' ,'category_fix'));
}

public function warung_plain($category , IndexController $objek){
    $objek->get_warung_by_category($category);
}
```

**and last this is my route:**

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
Route::post('/ambil_kategori/{category}',    'IndexController@get_warung_by_category');
Route::get('/warung_plain/{category}', 'IndexController@warung_plain');
```

Comment: you haven't explained what the problem is? are you seeing an exception or it just doesn't work?

Comment: it just doesnt work, maybe i wrong when i use routing in laravel 5, but i dont know why

Comment: the problem is div id="warung-plain" still empty after i click the link.

Comment: ok so you need to check your console (F12) and Laravel logs to see what is happening

Comment: ok dude it says "POST http://localhost/ambil_kategori/%7Bcategory%7D 404 (Not Found)" , yea i know thats wrong, but i dont know the right way to fill ajax url in laravel -_-

Answer (score 2):

Because you are making a post i think you need a token.

Here you can read the documentation about that [csrf-x-csrf-token](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token).

**Summarising you need to:**

```
// insert a meta tag to generate a tocken
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

// use the tocken in the header http request
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

**In your code it would be :**

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': {{ csrf_token() }}
    }
}).ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //after passing data category then system will append 
    //html code to id="warung-plain"
    url: "/ambil_kategori/{category}",
    data: {category: category},
    success: function(res) {
        $('#warung-plain').load("/warung_plain/{category}");
    }
});
```

Please note that the syntax `{category}` for blade is wrong, it should be like `{{ $category }}` if you have a variable or `category` if it's just a string.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a lot wrong here. You are using post, but aren't actually creating a new resource item. Secondly, your warung_plain function doesn't return anything? You should be doing a get against this route

```
/ambil_kategori/{category}
```

Additionally in your JS you aren't posting against the right url. You should be POSTing to (if for some reason you want to do it this way):

```
'/ambil_kategori/'+category
```

Suggest you re-read the L5 documentation

Comment: i have no idea the right way to write the correct url in ajax if i route with laravel 5